# Including Java classes in PHP script

Tags: java, php

I want to include Java class to my PHP script, can some one help me with the syntax and the path.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If it is PHP code, what makes you think you can include a Java class?

Comment: I have a banana, please tell me how to make it work with a jet engine.

Comment: @Marc B: 1) Use the banana to train a monkey (You may need to procure a bell also, see Pavlov). 2) Wait for monkeys to evolve and take over world. 3) Wait even longer until monkey's develop jet engine (possibly banana based, but that's purely bonus material). 4) Win.

Answer (score 2):

You will need the PHP4 Java extention or for PHP5 you can check out the PHP/JAVA Bridge.  [PHP/JAVA](http://php.net/manual/en/book.java.php)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it does not give a clear code of including Java.

Comment: There are examples for both: [PHP/JAVA Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/examples.php) and [PHP4 Java Extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/java.examples.php)

Answer (score 0):

PHP is built with C++ so I don't think you can really include any Java code with it. You'd have to re-write all the classes as C++ to build as a PCLE extension or just native PHP code. Maybe take a look at [Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/), but I don't have experience with it.